# Problem with function declaration in C when the 1st argument is a struct type

Tags: c, function, function-declaration

I am using a C code for some purpose written by some other person. While compiling the program :

> warning: implicit declaration of function ‘shine’
> [-Wimplicit-function-declaration

I am giving some part of the code below:

```
struct attribute
{
    int type, symb;      
    float lower, upper;
} examples[MaxExs][MaxAtts];
```

Below is the code where inside func1(), shine() is called.

```
int func1()
{
    int e, r, nstrule;
    float lwstdist;
    ...
    shine(examples[e], &nstrule, &lwstdist, e);
    ...
}
```

Below is the function definition for shine().

```
int shine(ex, nstrule, lwstdist, leftout) 
struct attribute ex[];
int *nstrule, leftout;
float *lwstdist;
{
    ...
}
```

I just want to remove that warning. So I wanted to declare that at the start of the code. I tried using:

```
int shine(xxx, int*, float*, int);
```

I don't know whether I am doing it correctly and what will be in place of xxx. I am new to C. So I am unable to figure out. Along with this help if I can get some material to go through for this particular thing that will be a great help.

Comment: Oh – pre-ANSI syntax. It's been a while I've seen that last time... Instead of `xxx` you can place either `struct attribute[]` or `struct attribute*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place a forward declaration of `struct attribute`.

```
struct attribute;
int shine(struct attribute[], int*, float*, int);
```

Btw. Unnamed function parameters are not standard C.
Though many compilers accept as it is allowed in C++ and trivial to implement.

This feature will be added to C in the upcomming C23 standard.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working fine. Can I get some material to study for this purpose?

Comment: @Dev, I suggest reading "Modern C", it's using the modern idioms and syntax. It may be a bit difficult. The book is free available at https://gustedt.gitlabpages.inria.fr/modern-c/

Comment: Or you could just make the struct definition visible to the function.